# d3 adding drag and drop to packed circles

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add the ability to drag a circle from within one parent into another using this as the starting point: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535

I've added this code:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()

        .on("drag", function(d,i) {
            d.x += d3.event.dx
            d.y += d3.event.dy
            d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
                return "translate(" + [ d.x,d.y ] + ")"
            })
        });
```

and then tried attaching it like this:

```
svg.selectAll("circle").call(drag);
```

or

```
node.call(drag);
```

I've two problems, one is positioning the circle correctly as I drag (which I think is because I need to save the origin) and the other one is how to select a sub circle to drag as it is assuming I want the parent circle.  Ideally I'd like to be able to select any circle and be able to drop it into any other circle.  Is there a way of attaching the drag behaviour so this just works or do I need to look at the data structure in order to work out the lowest level circle I could be trying to drag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot going on in the Zoomable example and some of it is colliding with your intent. The quick fixes:

> One is positioning the circle correctly as I drag (which I think is because I need to save the origin).

Positioning the circle will require an update during the `ondrag` event. Here is what I used:

```
  var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d, i) {
      d.x += d3.event.dx;
      d.y += d3.event.dy;
      draw();
    });

  function draw() {
    var k = diameter / (root.r * 2 + margin);
    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.x - root.x) * k + "," + (d.y - root.y) * k + ")";
    });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r * k;
    });
  }
```

This `draw` function replaces the `zoomTo` function from the Zoomable example. Getting zoom to work with dragging is possible but it requires some extra thought.

---

> The other one is how to select a sub circle to drag as it is assuming I want the parent circle.

The Zoomable example has this CSS:

```
.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

If you want to target the leaf nodes, you will have to remove the `.node--leaf` portion of the CSS rule. You can also add a new rule to turn off events for the non-leaf nodes:

```
.attr("class", function(d) {
  return d.parent ? d.children ? "node node--middle" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
})
```

Note the addition of `node--middle`.

---

> Ideally I'd like to be able to select any circle and be able to drop it into any other circle. Is there a way of attaching the drag behaviour so this just works or do I need to look at the data structure in order to work out the lowest level circle I could be trying to drag?

You can drag it around without much trouble but the drag behavior will not automatically propagate changes into the data structure. If you want the actual hierarchy to change then there are a few extra steps required:

1. Detect where the leaf node ended
2. Change the parent of the leaf node appropriately
3. Recalculate the entire packing
4. Redraw/animate the new packing

Step 1 will be the tricky one. I do not have an example handy for helping with this. You can quickly detect the location that a drag event ended using the `dragstop` event — the trick will be figuring out which node is underneath that stopping point.

Comment: FWIW, here is the codepen I was playing with: http://codepen.io/MrHen/pen/GZQOPW.

Comment: Have forked you codepen and added a line so dragged circle appears on top.  Re problem with identifying what you dropped on.  Adding mouseover can detect which event you are dragging over but how to control the order of events so that if you save the value of the current_target in the mouseover event, you have access to it from the dragend event... http://codepen.io/phoebebright/pen/LNQejx?editors=0010

Comment: The mouse event should naturally trigger first. In your codepen, don't forget you turned off `pointer-events` for the middle nodes. You need dragging on leaf nodes but mouseover detection for middle nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not allowing you to drag the leaf-most children nodes because there's a css style with `pointer-events: none` applied to those nodes, so they never trigger drag. So you need to take out some or all of these classes:

```
.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

That'll make it possible to drag the children, but it will not prevent the ability to drag the parents. If you don't want the parents to be draggable, you have to NOT `.call(drag)` on them. The way to do it is to call `drag` on a subset of all circles, using `filter`.

So, after creating the circles, you can do this:

```
circle
  .filter( function(d) { return d.children ? false : true; } )
  .call(drag);
```

That will apply drag only to things that do not have children.

You are right about the incorrect positioning during drag being caused by not knowing the origin. I'm pretty sure you need to save the original circle position on `dragstart` and then add `d3.event.dx` to that position during drag.

Comment: that moves things on, see comment on other answer.  Thanks.